# Standard for recording audio on android phones?

Tags: java, android

I have an app that allows you to record short voice memos. Some users aren't able to record any audio(LG Ally being one device) at all. I'm using the MediaRecorder in android and am curious if there might be a "better" standard way to handle audio recording?

Comment: Are you getting crashes on the LG Ally, or something else? AFAIK, `MediaRecorder` and `AudioRecord` are your only two options.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Turns out once the user explained the crash in detail it was happening before the app was even recording :). I had a feeling it had to be something else since Media & Audio recorder were all I've ever seen in android. I ended up going with MediaRecorder since i was going the route of saving the files to the SD card. Thanks for your response!